# slide div from bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 640x480 div that is centered vertically and horizontally within my HTML page. I want a div to appear from the bottom edge of the div. I want that div to be 640x400. Essentially, the top 80px of the original div can be seen.

My question is, how do I make that new div appear from the bottom edge of the centered div?

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Could you post some code to start us off with. Just basic HTML and CSS you have. Or provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont got your css but, i recomend you to make your center div position:relative;
then you make the div thats should be animated absolute. Working example with animation here
http://jsbin.com/iqewuh/3/edit
css:

```
#i {
  width:640px;
  height:480px;
  background:red;

  position:relative;
}

#y {
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
  bottom:0;
  width:640px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="i">
    <div id="y"></div>
</div>
<a href="#!" id="animate">Animate</a>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#animate").click(function() {
    $("#y").animate({
      height: '+=400'
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#div1 {
   position:relative;
   width:640px;
   height:480px;
   background-color:blue;
}

#div2 {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   height:400px;
   width:640px;
   background-color:red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg4Vn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LSxGr/1)

Basically:

**HTML**

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#red {
  position:relative;
  width:640px;
  height:480px;
  background:#FF0000;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#blue {
  position:absolute;
  top:480px;
  width:640px;
  height:400px;
  z-index:1;
  background:#0000FF;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#blue').animate({top : 80 }, 1000);
});
```